# Puppet module repository and puppet dependency resolution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puppet

I am just trying to find out that does puppet have something similar to maven repo which allows me to resolve my puppet dependencies in IDE(geppetto) without having all the modules locally? As a java developer, having maven solve all my dependencies in Eclipse, I just can't put up with having all the red lines in my geppetto saying some modules are unknown resources.

eg.

```
define mymodule:A() {
    anothermodule:B
}
```

as the example above, is there anyway I can place "anothermodule" in a repo, configure local puppet pointing to the repo and resolve my dependency like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no.

However, you can either per project or per workspace set up a "Puppet Search Path" and point that to a local repo.

Also, one thing I have seen recommended from the geppetto user list is to create a dummy project and then set it as a linked or referenced project.